# Php перебрать аргументы

Tags: php

Есть функция

```
function edit($arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5) {
$args = [];
}
```

Как можно внутри её перебрать аргументы? И если аргумент равен = "hello", то добавить его в массив args

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php обратите внимание на функции начинающиеся на func_

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function edit() {
    $args = array_filter(func_get_args(), function($v){
        return $v == 'hello';
    });
    var_dump($args);
}

edit('a', 'b', 'hello', 'c', 'hello');
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

Comment: А как сохранить ключи аргументов?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs А разве в примере выше, вы видите, что они не сохраняются? Или что вы имели в виду, под словом "сохранить", какие именно ключи и где?

Comment: название переменной реально ли сохранить?

Comment: в PHP7 кстати есть новшество - функция может принимать неопределенное количество входных параметров `function sumOfInts(int ...$ints)` ... и великий `func_get_args()` уже не нужен   http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, в функцию передаются не переменные, а значения, которые им были присвоены при инициализации или в процессе выполнения сценария. После фильтрации, у вас есть индексы элементов массива. Если вам надо понять, как бы это выглядело в вашем коде, то, например, элемент с индексом 1 - это, в вашем случае, переменная `$arg3`, а с индексом 3 - переменная  - `$arg5` и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сто процентов, но тут бы ТСу хотя бы с PHP5 разобраться ;)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , как раз php7 стоит) не пойму синтаксис, прям так и пишется ...$ints?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs прям так и пишется.... в мануале же написано)